# Angular 5 package for Heiken-Ashi candlestick Stock chart

Tags: angular, charts

I could not find any Heiken-Ashi candlestick Stock chart package / library for angular 5. Any help/ source/ idea will be appreciated. How can i draw Heiken-Ashi candlestick chart in Angular 5 application.

Comment: Have you thought about using [highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/), and more specifically the [stockchart](https://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo) library? It is a very powerful, here is the [candlestick](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/intraday-candlestick/) example. There is a little bit of a learning curve but once you get your first chart up and running, it becomes easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented heikin ashi chart using Chart.JS financial charts plug in by drawing Candle stick or OHLC chart and Heikin ashi data created by using HeikinAshi javascript library from NPM.
I choosed Chart.JS over any other JS library as it generates chart in canvas control.